# Extracting hash key that may or may not be an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I'm making an API call that returns XML (JSON also available) and the response body will show errors if any. There may be only one error or multiple errors. When the XML (or JSON) is parsed into a hash, the key that holds the errors will be an array when multiple errors are present but will be just a standard key when only one error is present. This makes parsing difficult as I can't seem to come up with one line of code that would fit both cases

The call to the API returns this when one error

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><response><version>1.0</version><code>6</code><message>Data validation failed</message><errors><error><parameter>rptFilterValue1</parameter><message>Parameter is too small</message></error></errors></response>
```

And this when multiple errors

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><response><version>1.0</version><code>6</code><message>Data validation failed</message><errors><error><parameter>rptFilterValue1</parameter><message>Parameter is too small</message></error><error><parameter>rptFilterValue2</parameter><message>Missing required parameter</message></error></errors></response>
```

I use the following to convert the XML to a Hash

```
Hash.from_xml(response.body).deep_symbolize_keys
```

This returns the following hash.

When there is only one error, the hash looks like this

```
{:response=>{:version=>"1.0", :code=>"6", :message=>"Data validation failed", :errors=>{:error=>{:parameter=>"rptFilterValue1", :message=>"Parameter is too small"}}}}
```

When there are 2 errors, the hash looks like this

```
{:response=>{:version=>"1.0", :code=>"6", :message=>"Data validation failed", :errors=>{:error=>[{:parameter=>"rptFilterValue1", :message=>"Parameter is too small"}, {:parameter=>"rptFilterValue2", :message=>"Missing required parameter"}]}}}
```

When I first tested the API response, I had multiple errors so the way I went about getting the error message was like this

```
data = Hash.from_xml(response.body).deep_symbolize_keys
if data[:response].has_key?(:errors)
  errors = data[:response][:errors][:error].map{|x| "#{x.values[0]} #{x.values[1]}"}
```

However when there is only one error, the code errors out with undefined method 'values' for parameter

The only actual workaround I found was to test the class of the error key. When Array I use one method for extracting and when Hash I use another method.

```
if data[:response][:errors][:error].class == Array
  errors = data[:response][:errors][:error].map{|x| "#{x.values[0]} #{x.values[1]}"}
else
  errors = data[:response][:errors][:error].map{|x| "#{x[1]}"}
end
```

But I just hate hate hate it. There has to be a way to extract xml/json data from a key that may or may not be an array. The solution may be in the conversion from xml to hash rather than when parsing the actual hash. I couldn't find anything online.

I'll appreciate any help or tip.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ use `Object#is_a?` instead of direct class comparison; the latter would fail for all the derived classes. `data[:response][:errors][:error].is_a?(Array)` (or you might compare classes with inequality: `data[:response][:errors][:error].class <= Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails, [Array#wrap](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap) is available if you can do your `.dig` first:

```
single = {:response=>{:version=>"1.0", :code=>"6", :message=>"Data validation failed", :errors=>{:error=>{:parameter=>"rptFilterValue1", :message=>"Parameter is too small"}}}}

Array.wrap(single.dig(:response, :errors, :error))
```

This returns an Array of size 1:

```
[
  {
      :message => "Parameter is too small",
    :parameter => "rptFilterValue1"
  }
]
```

For multiples:

```
multiple = {:response=>{:version=>"1.0", :code=>"6", :message=>"Data validation failed", :errors=>{:error=>[{:parameter=>"rptFilterValue1", :message=>"Parameter is too small"}, {:parameter=>"rptFilterValue2", :message=>"Missing required parameter"}]}}}

Array.wrap(multiple.dig(:response, :errors, :error))
```

This returns an Array of size 2:

```
[
  {
      :message => "Parameter is too small",
    :parameter => "rptFilterValue1"
  },
  {
      :message => "Missing required parameter",
    :parameter => "rptFilterValue2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. So the wrap method makes the key an array... unless it's already an array, Makes sense!

Comment: Yep. It _basically_ does what you did, but addresses a few edge cases and wraps it up in the public class method. The code for it is short: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/wrap.rb#L39-L47

Answer (score 0):

You can parse XML with `Nokogiri` and `xpath`, which returns array even if selector points out single element

```rb
errors = Nokogiri::XML(xml_response).xpath('//error')
errors.map { |e| e.children.each_with_object({}) { |x, h| h[x.name] = x.content } }
```

Your API response with single error gives

```rb
=> [{"parameter"=>"rptFilterValue1", "message"=>"Parameter is too small"}]
```

and API result with multiple errors

```rb
=> [{"parameter"=>"rptFilterValue1", "message"=>"Parameter is too small"}, {"parameter"=>"rptFilterValue2", "message"=>"Missing required parameter"}]
```

If there's no `error` elements you'll get an empty array.